# How can I watch a property for changes within a filtered array of objects when I'm filtering by that same property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I do this:

```
$scope.$watch('item.completed', function(to, from){ …
```

in conjunction with this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{completed: true}" ng-controller="ItemCtrl"> …
```

Live plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pdFkEmxyqrzS6mc2AYo2?p=preview

Currently, when I change the `item` object's `completed` property, the `$watch()` is not firing.

I suspect it has something to do with the filter messing up object property's reference, but how can I accomplish this otherwise? I've also tried `$watch(…, …, true)` and `$watchCollection()` but neither has any effect.

Comment: I think there is something going wrong in the binding there. Any changes to the first list should also affect the second list since they should be bound to the same `$scope.items` object. Is the filtering breaking the binding somehow?

Comment: @pseudosavant Perhaps, but as the plunker shows, the filtered list items still disappear when checked/completed (which seems to indicate to me that the binding is still working).

Comment: I agree there's something weird happening with the binding. The `completed` property that you're setting with the checkbox is also the criteria for membership in the filtered list. But those items aren't being removed from the filtered list when the properties are updated.

Comment: @jdmcnair They are being removed for me in the second list, as I would expect. Are you saying they are not for you?

Comment: No, I'm talking about when the `completed` property is set in the first list (which is the same underlying list of objects before filtering, afterall), the filter is not re-evaluated on the second list.

Comment: Correct, it should not be. They are not linked.

Comment: Each controller creates its own scope, so items in the first instance of `ItemsCtrl` is different from the one in the second instance of `ItemsCtrl`. So it works as expected only.

Comment: Ah, right you are. I missed that each repeat has its own ItemsCtrl.

Comment: I think it's got to do with the fact that the filter on the list is driven by the property that you're watching. When you uncheck an item in the list, it's no longer a member of the list that's being watched.

Comment: @PSL clearly our expectations are different lol. The two lists should not be linked—rather one is showing a (working) unfiltered list, and the other is showing a (broken) filtered list.

Comment: I agree @jdmcnair, just not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Yes, it does have to do with the checkbox pulling the items out of the filter. If you're watching a second property that does not drive the filter then the watch works: http://plnkr.co/edit/PrPuFNwsi0wyIVcrOC5P

Comment: Interesting/nice plunker. Any idea why this is?

Comment: When the items are removed from ng-repeat using the filter their scopes will be destroyed, so you basically have no more watch on them.

Comment: The reason probably is that element is not in the dom any more when you uncheck

Comment: @PSL: so is there no way to filter a list of items based on a property that can be edited in that list?

Comment: @jdmcnair example works because elements are not removed when unchecked, not because he is using different property

Comment: @MurraySmith You could watch on `items` or bind a click event on the checkbox and find out what was changed. Probably i dont understand what you are trying to do though.

Comment: @jdmcnair I don't quite understand, but it seems odd to me that Angular would depend on the DOM here?

Comment: @MurraySmith angular attached scope a property on DOM element, when the element is removed from DOM they are gone and so are their watches. But what exactly you are trying to achieve. I still did not get what is the problem. You want to retain the watch?

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not about being removed from the DOM, it's about being removed from the list who's items are in the watch.

Comment: @jdmcnair removing from the list is what gets removed from DOM. Thats what angular does during the digest cycle.

Comment: @PSL correct, I want to  retain the watch, or at least find another way to do what the question title asks, with the addition that __the same property being changed is being used to filter the list__.

Comment: @MurraySmith one way could be to do this http://plnkr.co/edit/rCkjivDZPzkTsWhilfts?p=preview

Comment: @PSL: I agree with @jdmcnair, but could be wrong. `$watch()` looks at the object property's reference in `$scope`, and if that disappears because the `items` array gets filtered/altered, then the DOM will accordingly by updated thereafter. It doesn't really matter though.

Comment: @PSL: the plunker you linked outputs false duplicates and seems pretty inefficient as it loops through the entire array once for every item (and all its watches)

Comment: @MurraySmith that was not a solution, wanted to show you that reference on the parent still holds your actual property/

Comment: @MurraySmith `$watch() looks at the object property's reference in $scope` yes when that scope is removed so does the watch. it is not a watch on the scope.items[$index] on its parent. Thats what i showed in the plunker

Comment: Just place a watch on the items collection in your parent scope (ItemsCtrl) and figure out what was removed by using an id property or something on your object.

Comment: @PSL I have posted an answer that does something similar to what PSL was suggesting in his last comment of this 'threat', let me know if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for the scope destroy event and get the value from the event object:

```
.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function(o){log(o.targetScope.item.name + '(' + o.targetScope.item.completed + '):destroyed')});
    $scope.$watch('item.completed', function(to, from){
      log(from + ' --> ' + to);
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: +1, this is the possibly the only solution if OP really wants to solve this by place a watch on the item being removed on the ng repeated items controller (though its value will be always `true` when destroyed. lol). But i still don't understand why it there a watch.. :D Registering an [ng-click](http://plnkr.co/edit/5X3BjaUeXebRVjSEAtUl?p=preview)

Comment: I agree. But its always good to understand why smth is not working even if its not a good solution

Comment: @PSL: for the sake of argument... `ng-click` doesn't work for keyboard presses (however `ng-change` would). My examples use simplified code; in real usage it's possible that the value being watched in generated by something other than direct user input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not totally sure I understand the end-goal. I think you're saying that you want to be able to log when an item in your filtered list changes. I can think of a couple of imperfect approaches.

1. Forget about the watch entirely. Just call a function on `ng-change` for the checkbox input: http://plnkr.co/edit/IeAt4a31So7zjMJzptIp?p=preview
2. Create a deep watch on the items array itself via `$scope.$watch('items', listener, true)`. The third argument being `true` will cause an [**object equality**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) check to be used, then you can compare the before and after states of the array and log what changed each time: http://plnkr.co/edit/gg5DPWJhx8syhNhelFOT?p=preview

Neither is exactly a `watch` that gives you a specific changed item in the list, but I *think* you can get to what you ultimately need to do via those routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have the watch function fire if you use ng-show instead of filtering.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="{{item.completed}}" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
```

Comment: True, but this is a hack, and in my case I need to be able to count the filtered results anyway (e.g. `item in filteredItem = (item | filter:{completed:true})`)

Comment: Ah, okay. If that's the case, then it's a scoping issue with accidentally having two item lists. Josep's answer above shows a better way of building out the structure for both controllers to work with the single set of items.


For quick validation, just try putting both lists under the same controller.

Comment: Like so:

`<ul ng-controller="ItemsCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.completed"> {{ item.name }}
      </li>
      <hr>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{completed: true}" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.completed"> {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way to do it, but I guess that it does what the OP wants:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wGRJIGJbALjMQqeffCyF?p=preview

It also proves that jonasnas and PSL were completely right.

The idea is to do this in the Controllers:

```
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
      {name: 'item 1', completed: true},
      {name: 'item 2', completed: true},
      {name: 'item 3', completed: true},
      {name: 'item 4', completed: false},
      {name: 'item 5'},
      {name: 'item 6', completed: true},
    ];
    $scope.itemsToWatch=[];
    $scope.watchMe = function(item){
      var myIdx = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
      if($scope.itemsToWatch.indexOf(myIdx)==-1){
        $scope.itemsToWatch.push(myIdx);
        $scope.$watch('items[' + myIdx + '].completed', function(to, from){
          log(from + ' --> ' + to);
        });
      }
    };
  }])
  .controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
      $scope.$parent.watchMe($scope.item);
  }]);
```

I don't think that I would ever code anything like this in a real app, but it has been fun to find a way to solve the question, and I've learned a few things in the process.